# CMake: Linking multiple libraries to two executables in one command

Tags: cmake

I've got two executables both of which need to be linked to N libraries which are the same:

```
add_executable(MyExe1 main1.cpp)
add_executable(MyExe2 main2.cpp)

target_link_libraries(MyExe1 lib1 lib2 lib3 ... libN)
target_link_libraries(MyExe2 lib1 lib2 lib3 ... libN)
```

So I have to write `target_link_libraries` twice; once for `MyExe1` and once for `MyExe2`. Is there any way to shorten the way some common libraries are linked to two different executables? I am wondering if it's possible to link `lib1` ... `libN` libraries to both `MyExe1` and `MyExe2` in one command to avoid redundancy and make the CMake file cleaner.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `set` command to set a variable from a list of arguments:

```
add_executable(MyExe1 main1.cpp)
add_executable(MyExe2 main2.cpp)

set(LIBS lib1 lib2 lib3 ... libN)

target_link_libraries(MyExe1 ${LIBS})
target_link_libraries(MyExe2 ${LIBS})
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a cmake pseudo-library that lets you do define lib1AndLib2 so you could use it in something like "target_link_libraries(MyExe1 lib1AndLib2)"?

Comment: @JamesMoore Yes, it is called an [interface library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#interface-libraries), and you create it with `add_library(MyInterfaceLibName INTERFACE)`.